# Make event N rows of a Dataframe into a column Aggregated by date in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

| title | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| String one | 2016-12-02 |
| String two | 2016-12-02 |
| ... | ... |
| String twenty-five | 2016-12-02 |
| String twenty-six | 2016-12-03 |
| String twenty-seven | 2016-12-03 |
| ... | ... |
| String fifty | 2016-12-03 |

And I want to change it into a dataframe like this

| timestamp | top 1 | top 2 | ... | top 25 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2016-12-02 | String one | String two | ... | String twenty-five |
| 2016-12-03 | String twenty-six | String twenty-seven | ... | String fifty |

Basically i'm trying to make every 25 rows to become columns consecutively
and i'm not sure how big the dataset will be but it's going to have atleast a few years as date.

I know i'm suppose to use reshape or melt but I've been unsuccessful till now. Any help in how to tackle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea, where column A is your dates and column D is your strings

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo",
                         "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar"],
                   "D": ["1", "this text", "text other", "What", "migrate", "Data", "5", "6 saucisses", "Okayy"]
                   })
# Join with a character very specific, that you won't find in your rows
# Something like '#######'
df = df.pivot_table(values='D', index=['A'], aggfunc=lambda x: '#'.join(x))

df_test = df.D.str.split(pat='#',expand=True,)
```